# Look. It's a trap

Tags: bug

The link to start an account deletion is available only when I am suspended, and then it does not work, because I am suspended.

I have lost a major source of support.  My stability is deteriorating.  And I will eventually make a fool of myself here, unless I go away.

Sorry.  Nothing against you.  Just me and my brain.

Comment: That's a pity, but an understandable decision - personal life should have first priority. All the best with gaining back stability.

Comment: @jobermark sad to see you go, you're a smart person who has made several valuable contributions here. But volunteering on the internet should always take second fiddle to bigger issues happening in the non-digital realm.

Answer (score 1):

The link to request deletion of your user profile is here: [contact us](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/contact) form. Pick the reason "I need to delete my user profile".

There is some waiting period involved: first, a 24 hour countdown and *then* probably more waiting, until some Stack Exchange employer reviews your case and presses the big red button (there is additional oversight over the deletion of high-activity accounts).